# Object doesn't support this property or method with primefaces omnifaces timeout combination

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, primefaces, viewexpiredexception, omnifaces

Setup:
JSF, PrimeFaces 3.2, Omnifaces 1.1, JBoss AS 7.1.1, Final, Mojarra 2.1.7

I have a simple page (listed below) and I have set up omnifaces to deal with ViewExpiredExceptions for ajax calls. When the listed below page expires and I click on a primefaces button (ajax) on IE8, the expired error page shows up but with the following javascript error:

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method, Line: 1 Char: 5500 Code: 0 URI: blah blah/mywebapp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3.2

It doesn't seem to produce an error on other browsers.

My page (home.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="form_search">
            <p:commandButton id="idbtn1"
                actionListener="#{bean.doSomething}"
                value="Do something (ajax)!">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="idbtn2" ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{bean.doSomething}"
                value="Do something!">
            </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The timeout error page: expired.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
    Your session has timed out.
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The template layout.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-    revalidate" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        </f:facet>
        <base href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Web.xml has among other bits:

```
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

When I click on the second button after expiration, then  the expired page shows without javascript errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of PrimeFaces `update="@all"` in IE based browsers. The entire view is been replaced by `document.write()`, however IE based browsers doesn't properly load/initialize any `<script>` resources. See also this [PrimeFaces forum topic](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=67176#p67176). This will be addressed for [PrimeFaces version 3.4.2](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4731).

Until then, you can workaround it using the following JavaScript

```
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse;
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse = function(responseXML) {
   var newViewRoot = $(responseXML.documentElement).find("update[id='javax.faces.ViewRoot']").text();

    if (newViewRoot) {
       $('head').html(newViewRoot.substring(newViewRoot.indexOf("<head>") + 6, newViewRoot.indexOf("</head>")));
       $('body').html(newViewRoot.substring(newViewRoot.indexOf("<body>") + 6, newViewRoot.indexOf("</body>")));
    }
    else {
        originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

which needs to be loaded *after* PrimeFaces own JS resources; this can be done by referencing it in `<h:body>` with `target="head"`.

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="script.js" target="head">
    ...
</h:body>
```

Note that this assumes that the current view is using PrimeFaces components which should in turn force auto-inclusion of `primefaces.js` and `jquery.js` scripts. Otherwise you've to manually declare them.

Comment: Btw, to break it add oncomplete="showConfirmDlg();" to the first button. Then it will still show an error this time complaining about the script.js. showConfirmDlg above is a p:remote command. Add <p:remoteCommand name="showConfirmDlg" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    value="#{sessionScope.render}"
                    target="#{requestScope.render}" />
            </p:remoteCommand>
to see it breaks with Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line:3,Char: 4, Code: 0
URI: blah/javax.faces.resource/js/script.js.xhtml

Comment: You'd need to add an extra check if `responseXML` or `responseXML.documentElement` isn't undefined.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be making a difference, I'll continue trying

Comment: both responseXML and responseXML.documentElement are both good. It actually goes to: originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction.apply(this, arguments); so I don't really know what to do in that case