# JavaScript errors in IE8 with different Primefaces component

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntaxhighlighter

We are getting JS (apparently jQuery) errors in IE8

- when trying to close a `p:growl` or it is trying to autohide (sticky=false)
- when using `effect` attribute on various pf component (e.g. p:calendar)

e.g.: When clicking on the x to close a p:growl component the following js error message appears:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 21
Char: 52546
Code: 0
URI: http://myserver:port/myapp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces
```

Some infos:

- using

  - PrimeFaces 3.4.2 (also tested it with PF 3.3.x, 3.4.x, 3.5-SNAPSHOT)
  - Mojarra 2.1.12
- don't have a `update="@all"` on those pages. (also tried [this js from BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820010/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-with-primefaces-omnifaces-timeout), which is [supposed to be included in 3.4.2](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4731))
- we don't use the same name for `id` and `widgetVar` attribute

Comment: @Daniel: as this is a general problem, i don't know which code to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to the JavaScript library [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), which was included in the layout template. Replaced it was another one and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested forms in your code, delete them. You cannot have nested forms in HTML, see also [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

I had the same issue some days ago (jquery error when clicking a button that opens a dialog) under IE8, and I solved deleting nested forms.

Comment: we don't have nested forms. i have double-checked this